# QStandardItemModel append new items on top of the rest

Tags: c++, qt

i like to make my QStandardItemModel that populates items in qtreeview
to append rows on top the allready defined items in the view . 
something like the twitter view , new items first.
all i see in the QStandardItemModel is the appendRow/s that appends then to button.
this is what im using now.

```
SWidget *widget = new SWidget;
            QStandardItem *newItem = new QStandardItem;
            newItem->setSizeHint( widget->size() );
            appendRow( newItem );
            view->setIndexWidget( newItem->index(), widget );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[void QStandardItemModel::insertRow ( int row, QStandardItem * item )](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html#insertRow-3) inserts a row at `row` containing `item`. So instead of calling `appendRow(newItem);` call `insertRow(0, newItem);`